# what's the alternative of profile CPU in performance schema?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

We know that MySQL profile（https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html）can  displays user and system CPU usage times for a SQL statement, and the article also says that "The SHOW PROFILE and SHOW PROFILES statements are deprecated and will be removed in a future MySQL release. Use the Performance Schema instead;"

So maybe I know which wait or stage listed in the performance_schema.setup_instruments provide the same functionality as profile CPU ?

That is to say when we enable the wait or stage ,then we can see the user and system CPU usage times for a SQL statement in the table such as  events_waits_current`or`events_stages_current` or others performance schema related  tables ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found `PROFILE` to be useless for studying performance.  P_S seems to be a rehash of that.

They like to say that 99% of the time is spent in "Sending data" or one of a few other useless phrases.

You are better off posting your query here, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.